# How i can remove react-native button shadow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to figure out React Native. When I created button I see unexpected bottom shadow. How can i prevented? (Gray color)

[image]

Code:

```
<Button 
    title="LOGIN"
    color='#f2a743'
/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think thats possible. If you don't need a button elevation (shadow), you may create your own react-native button using using Touchables(TochableOpacity, TochableHighlight, TouchableWithoutFeedback). And it's not a big deal.

Please refer to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html).

```
renderButton = () => { 
  return ( 
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButton}> 
      <ImageBackground style={styles.button} source={require('./myButton.png')} >
      <Text>Press me</Text>
      </ImageBackground>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I successfully removed the shadow with `elevation: 0` in the button's style.

Answer (score 4):

The following code will remove button shadow

`style = {{ elevation: 0 }}`

Comment: This didn't work for me on `Button` Component. This certainly works on other types of Components, like `View` for adjusting "height" or "shadow". Anybody else have any luck?

Comment: Button does not have a `style` prop.

Answer (score 1):

Whats about using `css` to remove the shadow?

```
style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 0p;"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't use **style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 0p;"**  at all 
 there is multi way to approach this i personal use   **elevation: 0**

if you use router-flux for navigation pls consider that icons appear with shadow just on android but no shadow exist for ios version by default