# remove button outline native-base

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am trying to wrap an icon in a button. Like this:

```
            <Button
              style={styles.radioButton}
              onPress={() => {
                console.log('hdjwk');
              }}>
              <Icon
                style={styles.icon}
                name="circle-thin"
                color="#31C283"
                size={moderateScale(20)}
              />
            </Button>

...
  radioButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 0,
    borderColor: 'white',
  },
  icon: {
    paddingTop: moderateScale(12),
  },
```

However, when I wrap my icon with the button, the icon is pushed downwards and an outline starts to appear even though I have set the borderRadius as 0. How can I fix this such that it looks natural and there's no distinction between the background screen and the icon?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your button styles are pretty ok, i'd advise this though:

```
backgroundColor: 'white',
borderRadius: 0,
borderColor: 'transparent', //will make the colour fully opaque, but you could get an even better effect with 'border: none'
```

i noticed there is a box-shadow property on your button and this is most likely what is creating the border. so you'll need to set your button css as 'box-shadow: none'.

So align your icon in the center you will need to also set your your display as flex and then center your content. So the final button revisions should look like this(plain css)

```
{
  background-color: white, // could be transparent if you want it to be the same colour as 
the parent background
  border: none //to remove any border properties
  box-shadow: none

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 


  //NOTE: you might need to set up a width and height for the flex to take effect
}
```

```
{
   backgroundColor: 'white' 
   //or backgroundColor: 'transparent'
   borderRadius: 0,
   borderColor: 'white',
   elevation: 0,

   flex : 1,
   flexDirection: "column",
   justifyContent: 'center',
   alignItems: 'center'
}
```

read up on how to [Remove shadows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44862742/how-i-can-remove-react-native-button-shadow) or just use elevation: 0

Comment: border is not a valid style property in RN stylesheets.

Comment: That was becouse it was in plain css, i added an RN stylesheet version, try it.

Comment: p.s. you can read up more regarding flex here - https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox#flex

Comment: While this fixes the button outline problem, unfortunately, the button still doesn't work. I am guessing it gets overlapped by the View. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63229514/view-overlaps-with-touchableopacity?noredirect=1#comment111809722_63229514

Comment: you can try simulating a click event

Comment: you mean, with onPress? It's not working. The "click" doesn't do anything, that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to wrap the Icon and the Text Inside a TouchableOpacity? Or even just the Icon you can wrap that in a TouchableOpacitiy and then you can click it and set onPress Funktions like you would do it to a Button.

Reference: https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity#docsNav

You can also try other Touchable Wrappers React Native provides.

Comment: That does not seem to work for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63227106/touchableopacity-and-onpress-for-icons/63227187#63227187

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to use `TouchableOpacity` instead of `Button` . So you can easily do like this

> ```
>           <TouchableOpacity
>               style={styles.radioButton}
>               onPress={() => {
>                 console.log('hdjwk');}}
>            >
>               <Icon
>                 style={styles.icon}
>                 name="circle-thin"
>                 color="#31C283"
>                 size={moderateScale(20)}
>               />
>            </TouchableOpacity>
>
> ...
>   radioButton: {
>     backgroundColor: 'white',
>     borderRadius: 0,
>     borderColor: 'white',
>     alignItems: 'center',
>     justifyContent: 'center',
>   },
> ```

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't seem to work for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63229514/view-overlaps-with-touchableopacity?noredirect=1#comment111809975_63229514

Comment: I will check and verify it and will let you as a answer of your question.

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/dpmUu3!s4 I created a snack with the exact same styling. Oddly, it works here but not in my simulator. Any ideas why that might be? I even tried adding a touchableOpacity to the Text and whole row. Still, I am unable to click on them.